# MongoDB ObjectId creation at client

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Is it save to create a MongoDB ObjectID at client using library like mongoose and save the document to the server where there is a traffic of 500 W/S on the same collection, if it is save then can we use the same id after some time of creation let's just say 30 mins (I will put this id in a cache system to be used later)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the application or the driver supplies `_id` values, the server does not generate them.

It is possible for driver (or server) generated _id values to duplicate existing _id values in the collection. This requires a [much higher write volume](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/objectid.rst#design-rationale) than you are expecting (in the millions of writes per second).

Answer (score 1):

mongoId is generated at client side by drivers.

So Yes you can do this.

ObjectId()

```
Returns a new ObjectId value. The 12-byte ObjectId value consists of:

    a 4-byte timestamp value, representing the ObjectId’s creation, measured in seconds since the Unix epoch
    a 5-byte random value
    a 3-byte incrementing counter, initialized to a random value
```

None of the above depends on server.So you don't need a mongo server to generate mongoid

Since object id is generated at client side, Hence there is no chance of collision at server in-case of single client, but stands a remote change in case of multiple clients with very high write frequency.

Comment: Hi Holy_diver thanks for replying, but my question is regarding is it save to generate the mongodb id at client side as there is a chance of collision with server generated id.

Comment: That's what i am saying, object id is generated at client side, Hence no chance of collision at server. There may be some remote chance in case multiple servers are writing under very high concurrency.

Comment: @Holy_diver What are chances... my client side genereates an Id, unluckily it already exists in the database